# SQL query to subtract net position from same table

Tags: sql, sqlite, cordova

I'm developing a phonegap app - working out who owes who a drink. I think I'm close to a solution but can't work out the last part without outer join (which SQL Lite does not support).

The database is structured with user IDs representing the buyer and receiver, and separate drink types (beer, wine, cocktails etc). I want to go through and cancel drinks of the same type to work out who is ahead in each type.

The results should be a table with each drink code down the side, and the number owed (could be negative)

```
var sql = "select too.drinkType, ifnull(fro.cnt, 0) - ifnull(too.cnt, 0) as cnt FROM "+
"(SELECT drinkType, count(drinkType) as Cnt FROM drink "+
"WHERE boughtBy = "+0+" and boughtFor = " + id + " GROUP BY drinkType) too "+
" LEFT OUTER JOIN  " +
"(SELECT drinkType, count(drinkType) as Cnt FROM drink "+
"WHERE boughtBy = "+id+" and boughtFor = " + 0 + " GROUP BY drinkType) fro "+
"on too.drinkType = fro.drinkType "

tx.executeSql(sql, [], getDrinksNet_success);
```

This nearly works, but misses drinkTypes that were only returned by the second query (fro). I think an outer join is what I need, but phonegap doesn't seem to support that. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a query like this, where you count up or down depending on who bought the drink:

```
SELECT drinkType, SUM(CASE WHEN boughtBy = :id THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS cnt
FROM drink
WHERE (boughtBy = :id AND boughtFor = 0)   
OR (boughtFor = :id AND boughtBy = 0)
GROUP BY drinkType
```

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, you can implement a `FULL OUTER JOIN` by [combining](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) a left and a right outer join, and implement a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` by using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and exchanging the two tables.
Your query would then look like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM
(SELECT ...) too
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT ...) fro
ON too.drinkType = fro.drinkType
UNION
SELECT ... FROM
(SELECT ...) fro
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT ...) too
ON fro.drinkType = too.drinkType
```